# compile error related to <nav_msgs::Path> publisher

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, nav-msgs, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish the path produced by my `global_planner plugin` (named `my_global_planner`) using a publisher named `global_plan_pub`.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error when I try to compile my package (named `my_global_planner`).

It compiles successfully if I comment out the line `global_plan_pub.publish(plan)` from the `global_planner.cpp` file.

I have included my header file (named `global_planner.h`) and source file (named `global_planner.cpp`) below.

```
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >]’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:254:102:   required from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/publisher.h:113:7:   required from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/home/skpro19/catkin_ws/src/my_global_planner/src/global_planner.cpp:94:33:   required from here
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:125:14: error: ‘const class std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
     return m.__getMD5Sum().c_str();
            ~~^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >]’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:263:104:   required from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/publisher.h:113:7:   required from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/home/skpro19/catkin_ws/src/my_global_planner/src/global_planner.cpp:94:33:   required from here
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/message_traits.h:142:14: error: ‘const class std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’
     return m.__getDataType().c_str();
            ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/global_planner_lib.dir/src/global_planner.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/global_planner_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /home/skpro19/catkin_ws/build/my_global_planner; catkin build --get-env my_global_planner | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
```

`global_planner.h`

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <nav_core/base_global_planner.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <angles/angles.h>
#include <base_local_planner/world_model.h>
#include <base_local_planner/costmap_model.h>
#include <map>
#include<nav_msgs/Path.h>


#ifndef GLOBAL_PLANNER_CPP
#define GLOBAL_PLANNER_CPP

namespace global_planner {

    class GlobalPlanner : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner {

        struct Point {
            
            __uint32_t x, y; 

            bool operator==(const Point &p1 ) {    return ((p1.x == this->x) && (p1.y == this->y));  }   
            
            bool operator<(const Point &p1 ) const{    return (p1.x < this->x) ;  }   


        };


       


        struct Cell {

            Point point; 
            __uint32_t cost_till_now;

        };


        struct compare_cost{
            
            bool operator() (Cell &p1, Cell &p2) 
            {

                return p1.cost_till_now < p2.cost_till_now;
            }

        };

        public:

            GlobalPlanner();
            GlobalPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);

            void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);

            bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start,
                            const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,
                            std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan
                        );

            bool makePlanOne(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan );
            bool makePlanTwo(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan );


        private: 


            double heu(const Point &p1, const Point &p2);


            costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap_ros_;
            costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS *costmap_ros;
            __uint32_t size_x, size_y;
            ros::Publisher global_plan_pub;
            ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    
    };

};

#endif
```

`global_planner.cpp`

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <my_global_planner/global_planner.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <queue>
#include<math.h>

//register this planner as a BaseGlobalPlanner plugin
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(global_planner::GlobalPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)

using namespace std;

namespace global_planner {

  GlobalPlanner::GlobalPlanner (){

  }

  GlobalPlanner::GlobalPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
    initialize(name, costmap_ros);

  }


  void GlobalPlanner::initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){

    nh_ = ros::NodeHandle{"~abcd"};

    costmap_ros  = costmap_ros;
    costmap_ros_ = costmap_ros->getCostmap(); 

    size_x = costmap_ros_->getSizeInCellsX(); 
    size_y = costmap_ros_->getSizeInCellsY();

    cout << "global_frame: " << costmap_ros->getGlobalFrameID() << endl;

    

    global_plan_pub = nh_.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>( "my_global_path", 10000 );

  }


  double GlobalPlanner::heu(const Point &p1, const Point &p2) {
    __uint32_t sum = (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y);

      return sqrt(sum);

  }

  bool GlobalPlanner::makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan ){

    cout << "Inside the make_plan function!" << endl;

    //bool reached  = false;
    
    __uint32_t mx_i, my_i, mx_f, my_f;

    double wx_i, wy_i, wx_f, wy_f;

    wx_i = start.pose.position.x; 
    wy_i = start.pose.position.y;
    wx_f = goal.pose.position.x;
    wy_f = goal.pose.position.y;

    costmap_ros_->worldToMap(wx_i, wy_i, mx_i, my_i);
    costmap_ros_->worldToMap(wx_f, wy_f, mx_f, my_f);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Printing start pose and goal pose: " << endl;
    cout << "w_i: (" << wx_i << "," << wy_i << ") m_i: (" << mx_i << "," << my_i <<")" << endl;;
    cout << "w_f: (" << wx_f << "," << wy_f << ") m_f: (" << mx_f << "," << my_f <<")" << endl;;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Sleeping for 1 second!" << endl;
    ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
    cout << endl;


    for(int i =0 ;i  < 10; i++){

      geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pt = start;
      
      pt.pose.position.x = start.pose.position.x;
      pt.pose.position.y = start.pose.position.y + i;
      plan.push_back(pt);

    }

    nav_msgs::Path my_path;

    my_path.header = start.header;
    my_path.poses = plan;

    global_plan_pub.publish(plan);

    cout << "Returning true!" << endl;
    cout << "Sleeping for 2 seconds!" << endl;
    ros::Duration(2.0).sleep();

    return true;

  }

  
  
};
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380053/compile-error-related-to-%3Cnav_msgs::path%3E-publisher/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you are issuing the wrong target.
Perhaps it is `global_plan_pub.publish(my_path);` instead of `global_plan_pub.publish(plan);`.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-12**:
@miura Thanks. That solved the problem.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-06-12**:
I'm glad it was resolved.